# Prove: $\int_a^b e^{z_0t}dt=\frac{1}{z_0}e^{z_0t}|_a^b$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

From a complex variables online course, and I need to prove that
$$\int_a^b e^{z_0 t}dt=\frac{1}{z_0} e^{z_0 t}|_a^b$$
For every $0\neq z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Do I need to define some conour $\gamma$ to which I am integrating over?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the familiar fundamental theorem of calculus?  It's valid for complex-valued functions on the real line; just consider the real and imaginary parts separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest a decomposition of $e^{z_0t}$ into a Taylor series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z_0t)^n}{n!}$. The integral of the sum in this case is the sum of integrals (you might want to verify that you can make this change of limits), so you get an integral of one term to think about: $\int_a^b \frac{(z_0t)^n}{n!}dt$. Now, since $z_0$ is fixed (a constant), you get it out of the integral, and you obtain a real-valued function to integrate: $\frac{(z_0)^n}{n!}\int_a^b t^n dt$.

That's it. When you integrate the real integral $\int_a^b t^n dt = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\big|_{t=a}^b = \frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$
Multiply it back by $\frac{(z_0)^n}{n!}$ and reassemble your series.

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z_0^n}{n!}\left[\frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{z_0^n b^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} - \frac{z_0^na^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right]\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z_0^{n+1} b^{n+1}}{z_0(n+1)!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z_0^{n+1}a^{n+1}}{z_0(n+1)!}\\
&= \frac{1}{z_0}\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z_0^n b^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z_0^na^n}{n!}\right].
\end{align*}

The terms with $n = 0$ are equal for both series, so they cancel out.

Comment: I understand most of your comment. I get the following: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z_0)^n}{n!}\int_a^b t^n dt$ and now what?

Comment: I've edited the answer. If you want me to elaborate on how to continue the re-assembling of the sum, just ask.

Comment: Do you see where does the $\frac{1}{z_0}$ come from?

Comment: I can see this but not much over: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}/((n+1)\cdot n! = -x+e^x-1$

Comment: Edited again. Make a comment if something's not clear.

Comment: BTW, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}/((n+1)\cdot n!) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}/(n+1)!$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: the sum starts with $0$, this changes a lot: the first terms in series in point $a$ is equal to the first term for the point $b$, so they cancel out. Do you see now, why $n+1$ is ok there?

Comment: I will give it a try in a few moments. Thanks a lot